# 500 Internal Server

Tags: php, laravel

I have this 500 Internal Server Error problem after hosting my laravel application for hosting. Remembering that I am replacing an existing one that has no errors but has the same configuration.

I think it can be mine .htaccess

```
<Files "pma_6JFAoR104611Q9k">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/24
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>



    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
Options -Indexes
```

I just found another .htaccess file and it worked, but opens multiple boxes of continuous logins:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: did you change storage and bootstrap folders permissions?

Comment: yes they are like those of the other previous server. 0755 for folders and 0644 for files and my php conforms to laravel version 7.1

Comment: good,did you enable rewrite_module on your php config ?

Comment: Please take a look at your error logs and search for instances of `PHP Fatal` errors, then tell us what you're seeing. A 500 error could be caused by almost anything, from a missing package, to a missing project file, to bad permissions, all the way down to a slightly different PHP configuration. Your error logs will help us figure out what's going on, otherwise we can only throw random guesses your way.

Comment: I just found another .htaccess file and it worked, but opens multiple boxes of continuous logins

Comment: RewriteEngine On
 
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
 
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Just delete that line of code and it should work.

Comment: still continues with the multiple logins box below each other, there must be 100 and not stop appearing more and more

Comment: Actually both .htaccess files are correct, the error was in the "public / index.php" path, but now multiple login boxes appear to me

Comment: I did the whole process, but the boxes still keep appearing below each other, what could it be?